# Cancelling current dialog in elegant way using interruptions (botframework)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

**TL&DR**

OnContinueDialogAsync method of ComponentDialog class, should allow to interrupt dialog. But when we have 3 dialogs: MainDialog>SubDialogA>SubDialogAA, and we are inside of SubDialogAA, interruption commands will always be catched by MainDialog. How to allow catching of interruptions "higher" in SubDialogs (when those are active), without removing this logic from MainDialog?

**More Details**

So as per this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp we should handle interruptions with CancelAndHelpDialog class containing interruptions handling and then other dialogs should derive from this dialog.

Below is CancelAndHelpDialog

```
public class CancelAndHelpDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        public InterruptionsHandleDialog (string id)
            : base(id)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

                switch (text)
                {
                    case "help":
                    case "?":
                        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Help", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);

                    case "cancel":
                        return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

We have 3 dialogs and each of them derive from CancelAndHelpDialog:
Main Dialog > SubDialogA > SubDialogAA (> means that this dialog calls other one with BeginDialogAsync)

Now I've tested 'help' from all three dialogs and it works. But it is called from MainDialog as messages are caught by MainDialog interruptions handling.

But then, 'cancel' will work as expected only in MainDialog, as it will always be caught there and will cancel MainDialog.

What would be elegant way to allow cancelling current dialog (using CancelAllDialogs) when we are in SubDialogA or SubDialogAA?

Also, is there any point for SubDialogA and SubDialogAA to derive from CancelAndHelpDialog, if everything would be caught by MainDialog anyway?

Comment: This question is confusing: "What would be elegant way to allow cancelling current dialog (using CancelAllDialogs) when we are in SubDialogA or SubDialogAA?" Why do you say "using CancelAllDialogs" if you only want to cancel the current dialog? Do you want to cancel all dialogs or just one?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've tested it and CancelAllDialogs is actually canceling only dialog where it was called and its child dialogs. When removed interruptions handling from MainDialog, sending 'cancel' while in SubDialogA, resulted with returning to MainDialog. And when removed interruption handling from MainDialog and SubDialogA, sending 'cancel' while in SubDialog AA allowed me to end SubDialogAA and go back to SubDialogA.

Comment: ^about last sentence - thats what I wanted to achieve but I also want to keep the interruption logic in MainDialog and SubDialogA as sometime those will be the active dialogs that should handle the interruption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that if dialog is active its DialogContext (innerDc) has Child property equal to null. This allow to execute interruptions only for active dialog:

```
public class CancelAndHelpDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        public InterruptionsHandleDialog (string id)
            : base(id)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message && innerDc.Child == null)
            {
                var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

                switch (text)
                {
                    case "help":
                    case "?":
                        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Help", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);

                    case "cancel":
                        return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, yeah I marked it as answer but Have feeling that thats not most elegant way to handle it. But so far it was working in all scenarios for my bot. Maybe someone will figure out something better/more accoring to the practices.